# Component Not Re-rendering all Though State of the prop is Changing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a score keeper component using ReactJs. I am working with vite for local server setup.My score keeper component is working but when i created a form component to add players in the score table. I see no changes in component even though the dev tools show that the prop state is changing.

The Main component where the state lives is:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import ScoreKeeper from './ScoreKeeper.jsx';
import EnterFormScore from './EnterFormScore.jsx';

export default function ScoreKeeperInterFace() {
  
  const [players,setPlayers]=useState(["Kartik","Rohit","Virat","Dhoni","Smith"]);
  const addToTable=function (Name) {
    setPlayers([...players,Name])
    
  }
  return (
    <>
    <ScoreKeeper teamNames={players} target={10}/>
    <EnterFormScore add={addToTable}/>

    </>
  )
}
```

The ScoreKeeper component:

```
import {useState} from "react"
import {v4 as uuid } from "uuid"
import TeamScore from "./TeamScore.jsx";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"

export default function ScoreKeeper({teamNames,target=11}){

    const [winner,setWinner]=useState(false);
    const [teamScores,setTeamScores]=useState(teamNames.map(e=>(
            {id:uuid(),Name:e,Score:0}
    )));
    
    const IncreaseScore=(id)=>{

        if(!winner)
        {setTeamScores(curr=>(
            curr.map((e)=>{
                if(e.id===id){
                    if(e.Score===target-1){
                        setWinner({Name:e.Name,id:e.id,winner:true})
                    }
                    return {...e,Score:e.Score<target?++e.Score:e.Score}
                }
                else { return {...e} }
            })
        ))
        }
    }

    const DecreaseScore=(id)=>{

        if(!winner){
            setTeamScores(curr=>(
                curr.map((e)=>{
                    if(e.id===id){
                        return {...e,Score:e.Score===0?0:--e.Score}
                    }
                    else { return {...e} }
                })
            ))
            }
    }

    const Reset=function (){
        setTeamScores(curr=>(
            curr.map((e)=>(
                {...e,Score:0}
            ))
        ))
        setWinner(false)
    }

    return <div className="flex flex-col items-center border rounded-md w-[fit-content] h-auto px-3 pt-3 shadow bg-slate-400">
        {winner.winner && <h1>The Winner is: {winner.Name}</h1>}
        <div className="flex space-x-1">{teamScores.map(e=>(
        <TeamScore inc={()=>{ IncreaseScore(e.id)}} dec={()=>{DecreaseScore(e.id)}} Name={e.Name} Score={e.Score}/>
    ))}
    </div>
    <Button onClick={Reset}>Reset</Button>
    </div>

}
```

EnterFormScore component is:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Button from "@mui/material/Button"

export default function EnterFormScore({add}){

    const [player,setPlayer]=useState("");

    const ControlForm=function (e){
        setPlayer(e.target.value);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input id="player_name" value={player} placeholder="Player Name" onChange={ControlForm}/>
            <Button onClick={() =>{ add(player)}}>Add To The Table</Button>
        </div>
    )

}
```

I have used tailwindCss and material UI also in this component. Please give me some insights i am unable to find a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `ScoreKeeper` component is not re-rendering because you're missing a `useEffect` inside the component.

The mapping of the `teamNames` inside `useState` is just running on initial render.

I'd initialize the `teamScores` state with an empty array and then add the following `useEffect` to `ScoreKeeper` component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let newTeamNames = [];
    teamNames.map((name) => {
      if (!teamScores.find((t) => t.Name === name)) {
        newTeamNames.push({ id: uuid(), Name: name, Score: 0 });
      }
    });
    setTeamScores([...teamScores, ...newTeamNames]);
  }, [teamNames, setTeamScores]);
```

**What is it doing?**

It checks if the team is already in the `teamScores` array, if not it will update the list with the new team. It's checked by name, would be better to check by id but there is no id (see comment below).

**Some notes to your code:**

- Name variables with camel casing e.g. `name` or `newTeamNames`
- I'd add the `uuid` in the top-level so you can use it later to identify your teams (not changed in the snippet)

I haven't thought about your data structure but fixed your issue.
You can find the complete demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dawn-resonance-596kzl?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30006356qcm5i5pjx%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c20002356qcr26xtco%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30003356qd4mazaxe%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30005356qgqpsqnh8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrxwp0c20002356qcr26xtco%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c00001356q89mcua1b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c20002356qcr26xtco%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c00001356q89mcua1b%2522%257D%252C%2522clrxwp0c30005356qgqpsqnh8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30005356qgqpsqnh8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30004356qx4xvg9b7%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30004356qx4xvg9b7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522SANDBOX_INFO%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxxtdnb014b356qz5g7pa3w%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clrxwp0c30003356qd4mazaxe%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrxwp0c30003356qd4mazaxe%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Full Code below (not working here):

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import {
  createRoot
} from "react-dom/client";
import {
  v4 as uuid
} from "uuid";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

function EnterFormScore({
  add
}) {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState("");

  const ControlForm = function(e) {
    setPlayer(e.target.value);
  };

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    input id = "player_name"
    value = {
      player
    }
    placeholder = "Player Name"
    onChange = {
      ControlForm
    }
    /> <
    Button onClick = {
      () => {
        add(player);
      }
    } >
    Add To The Table <
    /Button> <
    /div>
  );
}

function ScoreKeeper({
  teamNames,
  target = 11
}) {
  const [winner, setWinner] = useState(false);
  const [teamScores, setTeamScores] = useState(
    []
    // teamNames.map((e) => ({ id: uuid(), Name: e, Score: 0 }))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    let newTeamNames = [];
    teamNames.map((name) => {
      if (!teamScores.find((t) => t.Name === name)) {
        newTeamNames.push({
          id: uuid(),
          Name: name,
          Score: 0
        });
      }
    });
    setTeamScores([...teamScores, ...newTeamNames]);
  }, [teamNames, setTeamScores]);

  const IncreaseScore = (id) => {
    if (!winner) {
      setTeamScores((curr) =>
        curr.map((e) => {
          if (e.id === id) {
            if (e.Score === target - 1) {
              setWinner({
                Name: e.Name,
                id: e.id,
                winner: true
              });
            }
            return { ...e,
              Score: e.Score < target ? ++e.Score : e.Score
            };
          } else {
            return { ...e
            };
          }
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const DecreaseScore = (id) => {
    if (!winner) {
      setTeamScores((curr) =>
        curr.map((e) => {
          if (e.id === id) {
            return { ...e,
              Score: e.Score === 0 ? 0 : --e.Score
            };
          } else {
            return { ...e
            };
          }
        })
      );
    }
  };

  const Reset = function() {
    setTeamScores((curr) => curr.map((e) => ({ ...e,
      Score: 0
    })));
    setWinner(false);
  };

  return ( <
    div className = "flex flex-col items-center border rounded-md w-[fit-content] h-auto px-3 pt-3 shadow bg-slate-400" > {
      winner.winner && < h1 > The Winner is: {
        winner.Name
      } < /h1>} <
      div className = "flex space-x-1" > {
        teamScores.map((e) => ( <
          TeamScore id = {
            e.id
          }
          inc = {
            () => {
              IncreaseScore(e.id);
            }
          }
          dec = {
            () => {
              DecreaseScore(e.id);
            }
          }
          Name = {
            e.Name
          }
          Score = {
            e.Score
          }
          />
        ))
      } <
      /div> <
      Button onClick = {
        Reset
      } > Reset < /Button> {
        /* <h2>Debug</h2>
              <pre>
                teams:
                {JSON.stringify(teamNames, null, 2)}
                scores:
                {JSON.stringify(teamScores, null, 2)}
              </pre> */
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }


  // inteface
  const ScoreKeeperInterface = () => {
    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([
      "Kartik",
      "Rohit",
      "Virat",
      "Dhoni",
      "Smith",
    ]);
    const addToTable = function(Name) {
      console.log("add player", Name);
      setPlayers([...players, Name]);
    };
    return ( <
      >
      <
      ScoreKeeper teamNames = {
        players
      }
      target = {
        10
      }
      /> <
      EnterFormScore add = {
        addToTable
      }
      /> <
      />
    );
  }


  const TeamScore = ({
    Name,
    Score,
    inc,
    dec,
    id
  }) => ( <
    div key = {
      id
    } >
    Name: {
      Name
    } <
    br / >
    Score: {
      Score
    } <
    br / >
    <
    button onClick = {
      inc
    } > Inc. < /button> <
    button onClick = {
      dec
    } > Dec. < /button> <
    hr / >
    <
    /div>
  );


  function App() {
    return ( <
      div className = "App" >
      <
      ScoreKeeperInterFace / >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }


  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
  const root = createRoot(rootElement);

  root.render( <
    StrictMode >
    <
    App / >
    <
    /StrictMode>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mui/material@5.15.6/umd/material-ui.production.min.js
"></script>
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mui/material@5.15.6/umd/material-ui.production.min.js
"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving a key value to the component that you want to re render. Because when the component key change, the component will be rendering again.
Example:

```
<div key={refresh}>{"Something to re-render"}  <div/>
```

if you change the refresh value, it will be re rendering.